# How to detect in GCC if a string instance use in printf?

Tags: c++

For example,

```
string hello = "hello";
printf("%s", hello);
```

What compiler option should I set in my gcc compiler to detect this?

Thanks!

Comment: you ought to always use -Wextra and -Wall, this will pick up on stuff like that. You can also turn some warnings in errors (both through the push and pop pragmas and the compiler args)

Comment: The simplest solution is not to use `printf`.  It can't be made to work with user defined types anyway, so it is practically worthless in C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-Wformat` (which is included in `-Wall`)

This gives the following warning for your use case:

> warning: format `'%s'` expects argument of type `'char*'`, but argument 2 has type `'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}'`

In any case, it's an error to pass a non-trivial type to elipsis, so the compiler should issue a diagnostic even without this warning setting. `-Wformat` is more useful for things like `printf("%s", 42);`.

Comment: how can I make -Wformat treat as error? I mean only -Wformat warning messages.